# Is updating on rowid the fastest way to update a large sqlite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using Sqlite in C# and have a very large database (around 6 million records) - I have used `select rowid from debug_all_table where rule=X` to retrieve a list of around 10,000 rows that I need to update (using an ignore column - `update to ignore=1`) or delete in the quickest way possible.

Initially I attempted deleting rows, but found this to be very slow and found people saying that deleting was a slow process. I changed to attempting to update an ignore column from 0 to 1 - initially searching on another value within the row - however, this was taking hours. 
I thought that switching to using an index (`rowid` in this case) would speed up the process as it would simply look for that `rowid` and delete that row, rather than having to check every row in the DB to see if the value of a specific column matched what I was asking for each of the 10,000 rows to be deleted - this still seems to be taking hours.

Am I right in thinking the following is the best way to update on `rowid`:

```
update debug_all_table set ignore=1 where rowid=@rowid
```

Or is this still searching every row each time and checking the `rowid`? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

My last thought is that I could just insert ones that I do not want to ignore into an interim table, drop the original table, and reinsert back into that (it needs to do similar updates on a loop). Inserting the initial 6 million records occurs in a matter of minutes, so this seems like it would solve my problem as it is only the update/delete that takes forever - but it feels like I must be missing something for this to be the quickest way to achieve what I want?

Comment: The best way to see if it's fast is to try it, and benchmark versus alternatives.